# Can I receive all messages in a AWS SQS message group with the aws sqs cli without deleting any of them?

Tags: amazon-web-services, queue

I've observed that if an AWS SQS queue has 7 messages, two of which are in the same message group, then the AWS SQS Console will allow you to poll for, and inspect, all 7 messages.

However, if I try to do the same thing with the aws sqs cli, I can only see 6 messages presumably because the second message in the group with multiple messages isn't visible until the first message is deleted.

Is there any way I can simulate the behaviour of the AWS SQS console with the aws sqs cli so that I can see all the messages without actually deleting the first message in the group with multiple messages.

Comment: I later realised that I can use a value of --max-number-of-messages parameter which is greater than 1 but it I can see that this could potentially create scenarios where the first message is seen, but the second one is not.

Suppose for example, there was 11 messages, with the last 2 in the same message group and I used a --max-message-count of 10. Then in this case, the first of the two messages would be received, but the second would be invisible until the first is deleted. Admittedly, the SQS console mighjt also behave this way - I don't know.